# How to upgrade ffmpeg to the latest version

Tags: ffmpeg, upgrade

I am looking to upgrade ffmpeg to the latest version if i run

```
yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
```

I get the following

```
Setting up Install Process
Package ffmpeg-0.6.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ffmpeg-devel-0.6.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Then if i run

```
 ffmpeg -i P1010989.MOV -vcodec copy -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k ouet.mp4
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'P1010989.MOV':
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11584 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 640x480, 11315 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s
Unrecognized option 'b:a'
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FFmpeg Linux Builds
> FFmpeg Debian packages for Oldstable, Stable, Testing, Unstable
> (amd64, i386, powerpc, sparc, ia64, armel, mips, mipsel) are available at
> [deb-multimedia](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/).
>
> FFmpeg Ubuntu packages for Precise, Oneiric, Natty, Maverick, and Lucid
> (amd64, i386) are available at
>
> [Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg).
>
> FFmpeg Redhat and Fedora packages for EL, Fedora Rawhide
> (i386, x86_64) are available at
> [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/).
>
> FFmpeg static builds are available at
> [FFmpeg Static Builds by Burek](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) and
>
> [FFmpeg Static Builds by Relaxed](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24633983/ffmpeg/index.html).

[`ref`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: [Compiling](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) or using the static builds is generally recommended instead of the deb, rpm, and PPA because these are usually old.

Comment: Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA link is outdated, check here: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/